# Riccati equation involving multiple variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, partial-differential-equations

Hi I have this differential equation but I am not sure if it is solvale. If it is, it would be great if someone can shed some light on how to solve it. The equation is

$$0=K+\left(l_1(x)+\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}+l_2(x)\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}+l_3(y)\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}\right)h+P(x,y)h^2.$$

Here, $l_1,l_2,l_3$ are simple linear function such as $l_1(x)=ax+b$ and $h(t,x,y)$ is a funtion of $t,x,y$. $K$ is a non-zero constant and $P(x,y)$ is a polynomial of $x,y$ of degree two.  All variables sit in $\mathbb{R}$.

Obviously, if $K=0$ this equation can be solved more easily as a standard Ricatti equation. We just use the ansatz $h=\exp(Q(x,y))$ with $Q$ being a second order polynomial. But now with the $K$ here I am clueless.

Thank you very much.

Comment: By a "polynomial of order two", do you mean a "polynomial of *degree* two"?

Comment: Also, are you sure the equation is correct? Shouldn't it be $l_1(x)\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}$ instead of $l_1(x)+\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}$?

Comment: Yes I mean of degree two. Sorry for my wording. I am sure the equation is correct. It is a sum instead of product.

Comment: Back to $K=0$ for a sec, your ansatz has no $t$ in it. Is it right?

Comment: I assume the polynomial Q to involve t in its parameters. e.g. a(t)+b(t)x+...